# Increment an IntVar after condition

Tags: constraint-programming, choco

I'm using the choco solver to solve my constraint problem. Is it possible in Choco to increment an IntVar after a condition like model.ifThen?

Comment: `x = x + 1` is a normal construct in programming but it is not a valid constraint. You can do something like `y = if condition then x+1 else x`

Comment: Does this increment my variable ?                                                                 model.arithm(gisement_courant, "=", gisement_courant.getValue() +1)

Answer (score 0):

In constraint programming, you NEVER increment a variable. It is a declarative (not imperative) paradigm where instead of describing how to compute a solutions (operations on values), you just post constraint that must be satisfied. x=x+1 is a nonsense in constraint programming, leading to "no solution".